# How to set Radius for CLLocationManager in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have Requirement where i have to show Alert View to the User, when the User Cross the Radius from the Point.
How to set Radius.?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create the region using:

```
CLLocationDegrees latitude = <YOUR_LATITUDE>;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = <YOUR_LONGITUDE>;

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

CLLocationDistance radius = GEO_FENCE_RADIUS;

CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:title];
```

Next you have to monitor the region by:

```
 [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

Then You can track users when they enter or exit by the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {

      //Show your alert as they are entered the region

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
          didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
    //Show your alert as they are exited the region

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {


}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
              withError:(NSError *)error    {


}
```